# iPad focus-event

Tags: javascript, ipad, focus

I try to get the following working:

I have a form containing selectboxes and inputs.
There are two buttons on top of the virtual keyboard - "next" and "previous".
Navigating through the input fields works.
When I reach a selectbox (by pressing "next"), the keyboard stays and the selectbox shows its items.
When I select an item by tapping on an item of the selectbox, the element is selected and the keyboard disappears.

That's not what I want.
I want the next input or selectbox to be focused or the keyboard to stay.

I read (and tested) that the focus event does not work.
Is it possible to get this running by a workaround?

THX!

Answer (score -1):

then assign the first responder to the next ui element and the keyboard will remain visible. You should do this in the code that accepts the input from  the selectbox.

I am speculating, since there is no code included in the question, but I think the suggested approach should work

Comment: Hi! I do not fully understand what you wrote. What do you mean with "first responder"?

Comment: @eventhorizon http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW7

Comment: @eventhorizon is referring to HTML pages, not a native application.